# Controlling .DS_Store files in Sierra

Tags: finder, macos, folders

What exactly has changed in regard to `.DS_Store` files creation with the release of Sierra?

Currently I am a bit confused about the behaviour (changes?) of Finder, the filesystem or certain GUI settings.

When showing all files like with `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE` the .DS_Store files remain invisible. But then the Trash is always shown as 'full' since apparently that .DS_Store file gets recreated almost instantly? Of course, opening the Trash after just deleting it reveals nothing in Finder since TFF is now blind to .DS_Store files.

**Can the Trash be taught to also ignore .DS_Store files?**

Previously it was believed that Finder only creates .DS_Store files when accessing a certain directory hierarchy with a concrete 'view'. Now, after foolishly using Finder for copying a huge directory from an external drive to a user directory on the root volume that did not contain any .DS_Store files my cleanup routine revealed that apparently *every* hierarchy level had a new .DS_Store file added – despite never being viewed with Finder. Several thousand useless .DS_Store files created by just copying a folder structure?

**Can somebody either at least confirm this behaviour, or even better know a way to prevent this obnoxious behaviour in Finder?**

Comment: If the directory is a network location, DS_Store can be turned off (they won't be created within it, but can still be copied). I don't know of any other way of controlling them.